Is there a solution for using data-driven (FeatureCollection properties) variables within the Images/Image element? @rnmapbox/maps
I want to display different icons (MaterialCommunityIcons name) on the map with different background colors (SVG fill) as SymbolLayer. The data should be used dynamically from the FeatureCollection. Is there a solution for this?
name=['get', 'iconname']
fill=['get', 'iconcolor']

It works with the CircleLayer, but I don't know how to get the variables into the Images/Image tag.
<Images>
    <Image name="image-for-a-symbo-layer">
        <View
            style={{
                borderRadius: 10,
                backgroundColor: 'gray',
                padding: 8,
                margin: 16,
                width: 100,
                shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 8},
                shadowOpacity: 0.2,
            }}
        >
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name=['get', 'iconname']
                color="#ff0000"
                size={60}
            />
            <Svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 90 123">
                <G id="a" clip-path="url(#b)">
                    <Path
                        d="M17"
                        transform="translate(-3.291 -3.292)"
                        fill=['get', 'iconcolor']
                    />
                </G>
            </Svg>
        </View>
    </Image>
</Images>

